# Linear represenation of a group(can be infinite also)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let G be a group and let $\sigma :G \rightarrow GL(V) $ be a representation of G. Assume $\sigma$ is reducible. That is $\sigma=\sigma_1 \oplus \sigma_2\oplus .... \oplus \sigma_k $ or interms of G submodules, $V=V_1\oplus V_2\oplus ...\oplus V_k$. Then is it true that $G=G_1\times G_2...\times G_k $? I am not sure this result. Intuitively I feel it is right. I am unable to produce such subgroups $G_k's.  Please help me for proving this or disproving this.

Comment: No, decomposability of any given representation is not related to decomposability of the group. Also note that what you describe is stronger than being reducible.

Comment: Okay... Thank you so much...